# How do you mute the lobby music in Halo: The Master Chief Collection when playing multiplayer?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I want to be able to listen to my own music/podcasts while playing Halo: The Master Chief Collection online but the lobby music drowns out the audio.

There doesn't appear to be any options in the audio section of the menu to either mute the music or at least turn it down.

Is there a way to mute the lobby music in Halo: MCC?

Answer (score 1):

Try muting the sound on your headphones and use the TV volume instead if you're using headphones.

Comment: If you have an edit to your answer, please use the edit button instead of posting another answer.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a way man, it's part of the game, the only option is to wait for the creators to fix the audio option